# How to share the same dependency injection container in TestNG with guice

Tags: dependency-injection, testng, guice

I run multiple `TestNG` *7.4.0* suites in parallel using something like (follows kotlin code, but it is the same in java, there is no language dependency):

```
    val testNG = TestNG()
    with(testNG) {
        setXmlSuites(allMyXmlSuites)
        suiteThreadPoolSize = threadCount
    }
    LISTENERS.forEach { testNG.addListener(it) }
    testNG.run()
```

In my suites i configure the parent module like this

```
suite.parentModule = SuiteParentModule::class.java.name
```

My problem is that inside `SuiteParentModule` I have a singleton that is invoked multiple time, exactly the number of times that are the suites invocation. So I guess every suite has an independent instance of `Injector`. Here the provider method that logs multiple time:

```
@Provides
@Singleton
fun provideEnvironmentUrls(): EnvironmentUrls =
    EnvironmentUrls(
        System.getProperty("url")
    ).also { logger.info("Using default $it") }
```

Is there any way to make sure the dependency injection container provided by `TestNg` using `Guice` will remain the same, thus having real singletones provided?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that, even if using `TestNG.setParentModule()`, multiple suites will have multiple injectors.

**I managed to get only one injector created by moving my code into a single suite.**

Further information can be obtained at [the issue opened in the TestNG git](https://github.com/cbeust/testng/issues/398).